# Compress text file to tar.bz2 format on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, compression, tar

How can I convert a sample.txt (**uncompressed**) file to sample.tar.bz2 format using **Ubuntu 10.04** command shell?

Comment: `bzip2 sample.txt`

Comment: bzip2 -c sample.txt > sample.txt.bz2
@suspectus straight up would delete the original file, (which could be in use!) and print to stdout, not file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `tar` to achieve this :

```
tar -cjf sample.tar.bz2 sample.txt
```

`tar` is a program used to manage archives, the options here are `-c` to create an archive (it would be `-x`to extract one), `-j` to use `.tar.bz2` format, and `-f` to specify output archive name.

For more info : `man tar`.